# SQL Server 2005 - writing an insert and update trigger for validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I'm pretty bad at SQL, so I need someone to check my trigger query and tell me if it solves the problem and how acceptable it is. The requirements are a bit convoluted, so please bear with me.

Suppose I have a table declared like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents
(
    id int identity primary key,
    number1 nvarchar(32),
    date1 datetime,
    number2 nvarchar(32),
    date2 datetime
);
```

For this table, the following constraints must be observed:

- At least one of the number-date pairs should be filled (both the number and the date field not null).
- If both number1 and date1 are not null, a record is uniquely identified by this pair. There cannot be two records with the same number1 and date1 if both fields are not null.
- If either number1 or date1 is null, a record is uniquely identified by the number2-date2 pair.

Yes, there is a problem of poor normalization, but I cannot do anything about that.

As far as I know, I cannot write unique indexes on the number-date pairs that check whether some of the values are null in SQL Server 2005. Thus, I tried validating the constraints with a trigger.

One last requirement - the trigger should have no inserts of its own, only validation checks. Here's what I came up with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_requisite_uniqueness
ON [Documents]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NUMBER1 NVARCHAR (32)
    DECLARE @DATE1 DATETIME
    DECLARE @NUMBER2 NVARCHAR (32)
    DECLARE @DATE2 DATETIME
    DECLARE @DATETEXT VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE inserted_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT number1, date1, number2, date2 FROM Inserted

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
        RETURN

    OPEN inserted_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor into @NUMBER1, @DATE1, @NUMBER2, @DATE2

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   

        IF (@NUMBER1 IS NULL OR @DATE1 IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            IF (@NUMBER2 IS NULL OR @DATE2 IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                RAISERROR ('Either the first or the second number-date pair should be filled.', 10, 1)## Heading ##
            END
        END

        IF (@NUMBER1 IS NOT NULL AND @DATE1 IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Documents WHERE number1 = @NUMBER1 AND date1 = @DATE1) > 1)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                SET @DATETEXT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DATE1, 104)
                RAISERROR ('A document with the number1 ''%s'' and date1 ''%s'' already exists.', 10, 1, @NUMBER1, @DATETEXT)
            END
        END
        ELSE IF (@NUMBER2 IS NOT NULL AND @DATE2 IS NOT NULL) /*the DATE2 check is redundant*/
        BEGIN
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Documents WHERE number2 = @NUMBER2 AND date2 = @DATE2) > 1)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                SET @DATETEXT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DATE2, 104)
                RAISERROR ('A document with the number2 ''%s'' and date2 ''%s'' already exists.', 10, 1, @NUMBER2, @DATETEXT)
            END
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor 
    END

    CLOSE inserted_cursor
    DEALLOCATE inserted_cursor
END
```

Please tell me how well-written and efficient this solution is.
A couple of questions I can come up with:

- Will this trigger validate correctly against existing rows and newly inserted/updated rows in case of bulk modifications? It should, because the modifications are already applied to the table in the scope of this transaction, right?
- Are the constraint violations handled correctly? Meaning, was I right to use the rollback transaction and raiserror pair?
- Is the "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN" statement used correctly?
- Is the use of COUNT to check the constraints acceptable, or should I use some other way of checking the uniqueness of number-date pairs?
- Can this solution be optimized in terms of execution speed? Should I add non-unique indexes on both number-date pairs?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

A solution using a check constraint and an indexed view, based on [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/)'s answer:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Documents
(
    id int identity primary key,
    number1 nvarchar(32),
    date1 datetime,
    number2 nvarchar(32),
    date2 datetime,
    constraint CK_Documents_AtLestOneNotNull CHECK (
        (number1 is not null and date1 is not null) or
        (number2 is not null and date2 is not null)
    )
);
go
create view dbo.UniqueDocuments
with schemabinding
as
    select
        CASE WHEN (number1 is not null and date1 is not null)
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
            ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END as first_pair_filled,
        CASE WHEN (number1 is not null and date1 is not null)
            THEN number1
            ELSE number2
        END as number,
        CASE WHEN (number1 is not null and date1 is not null)
            THEN date1
            ELSE date2
        END as [date]
    from
        dbo.Documents
go
create unique clustered index IX_UniqueDocuments on dbo.UniqueDocuments(first_pair_filled,number,[date])
go
```

Comment: *Can this solution be optimized in terms of execution speed?* - ***Y-E-S-!!!*** First of all, ***get rid of the CURSOR!*** - you should ***never ever*** use a cursor inside a trigger - that's a sure fire way to kill all your system performance.....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, I didn't know that. But I'm not sure what I should use instead of the cursor to validate modified records.

Comment: 99.9% of the time, you do not need a cursor.  Whenever you feel your fingers typing "cur"..........stop and ask before your proceed.  My old company, people had to schedule a meeting to justify why they needed a cursor.  Effectively, they were outl@wed.  I've seen the need for a cursor once in the past 15 years.

Comment: And no, it will not handle any bulk operations. Triggers do not run on bulk operations at all. It only works on non-bulk-loads. And it will not do anything on existing rows because triggers are not checked on data already there when they are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the trigger, and use a check constraint and an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.90).aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Documents
(
    id int identity primary key,
    number1 nvarchar(32),
    date1 datetime,
    number2 nvarchar(32),
    date2 datetime,
    constraint CK_Documents_AtLestOneNotNull CHECK (
        (number1 is not null and date1 is not null) or
        (number2 is not null and date2 is not null)
    )
);
go
create view dbo.UniqueDocuments
with schemabinding
as
    select
        COALESCE(number1,number2) as number,
        COALESCE(date1,date2) as [date]
    from
        dbo.Documents
go
create unique clustered index IX_UniqueDocuments on dbo.UniqueDocuments(number,[date])
go
```

Which has the advantage that, although there is some "trigger-like" behaviour because of the indexed view, it's well-tested code that's already been deeply integrated into SQL Server.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this view not updatable? I need to enforce the constrains on new and modified records that the user inputs through the application.

Comment: @sdds - you continue to insert and update into the base table. The view and its index merely server to *enforce* the uniqueness.

Comment: I really like your solution, however, there are two problems. First, if a number1-date1 pair exists, an identical number2-date2 pair cannot be inserted. Second, if there is a record with number2='1' and date2='2011-1-1', inserting a record with number1='1', number2='2' and date2='2011-1-1' is not possible, because number1 is always a part of the index when it is not null (same problem with date1 always part of the index). Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question - anyway, please check my solution in the edit. It seems to work as needed, is it acceptable, or can it be done better?

Comment: I usually use MySQL and apply the validation rules in the server programming language (e.g. php, python, ruby). If I use SQL Server and check constraints, how I can return a custom message for each error type?

Comment: @JCarlos - there's nowt wrong with also checking at other levels if you want to supply custom error messages. The point of applying constraints is to ensure that, even if everything else goes wrong or people are trying to change data through ad-hoc queries, it's impossible for the database to *allow* incorrect data to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this logic instead (I didn't type it all as it takes ages), and definitely use SELECT 1 FROM ... in the IF EXISTS() statement as it helps performance. Also remove the cursors like marc_s said.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_validate_requisite_uniqueness
ON dbo.[Documents]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

 DECLARE @Number1 NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT TOP 1 number1 FROM dbo.Documents ORDER BY Id DESC)
 DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME        = (SELECT TOP 1 date1 FROM dbo.Documents ORDER BY Id DESC)
 DECLARE @Number2 NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT TOP 1 number2 FROM dbo.Documents ORDER BY Id DESC)
 DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME        = (SELECT TOP 1 date2 FROM dbo.Documents ORDER BY Id DESC)
 DECLARE @DateText NVARCHAR(100)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Documents AS D 
INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON D.id = I.id WHERE I.Number1 IS NULL AND I.number2 IS  NULL)       
BEGIN   
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RAISERROR ('Either the first or the second number pair should be filled.', 10, 1) 
END  

ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Documents AS D 
       INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON D.id = I.id WHERE I.Date1 IS NULL AND I.Date2 IS NULL)
BEGIN     
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  RAISERROR ('Either the first or the second date pair should be filled.', 10, 1) 
END


ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Documents AS D 
           GROUP BY D.number1, D.date1 HAVING COUNT(*) >1
          )

BEGIN 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  SET @DateText = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date1, 104))
  RAISERROR ('Cannot have duplicate values', 10, 1, @Number1, @DateText )
END
```

Comment: I think it's also possible to just use IF EXISTS() all the way instead of ELSE IF EXISTS() for the 2nd, 3rd and so on, perhaps someone with more experience can confirm it 100% :)

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear - I meant that a record is identified by one of the number AND date pairs. So, number1 and date1 are not null or unique, or, if one of these fields is null, number2 and date2 are not null and unique. I'll try to rewrite your your query and test it, thanks!

Comment: Ok, please let me know and vote if my idea helped you :) thanks.